# Application hangs when webbrowser is downloading files

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that contains multiple URLs of pictures I want to download, I am splitting this string and storing each URL in an array then loop inside the array to get each URL and download it, but the application is hanging until all this event is done. this is my code:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim cnt As Integer = 1
    Dim singleUrl As String() = allPicsURL.Split(New Char() {","c})
    ReDim Preserve singleUrl(UBound(singleUrl) - 1)
    For j As Integer = 0 To singleUrl.Length() - 1
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(singleUrl(j), "F:\Users\Dany\Pictures\Test\" & Date.Now().ToFileTime & ".jpeg")
        cnt += 1
    Next
    MsgBox(cnt - 1 & " Pictures were saved!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
End Sub
```

How do I stop my application from freezing?

Comment: How are you starting your background worker? Are you doing it like this       BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

Comment: you can use backgoround worker

Comment: on the button click: BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender, Nothing),
i change it to .RunWorkerAsync()?

Comment: Just changed it as u said Mike and application not hanging anymore, thanks for your help Sir

Answer (score 0):

you use the Backgroundworker

[you check this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet)